# Не работает слайдер на js. В чем ошибка?

Tags: javascript, slider

Почему-то не работают кнопки вперед/назад, которые должны листать фотки. В чем ошибка не могу понять?

[Код](https://jsfiddle.net/san4izl/on71hq0z/)

```js
let slider1 = new Slider({
  images: '.gallery-1 img',
  btnPrev: '.gallery-1 .prev',
  btnNext: '.gallery-1 .next',
})

function Slider(obj) {
  this.images = document.querySelectorAll(obj.images)
  let i = 0

  this.prev = function() {
    this.images[i].classList.remove('show')
    i--
    if (i < 0) {
      i = this.images.length - 1
    }
    this.images[i].classList.add('show')
  }
  this.next = function() {
    this.images[i].classList.remove('show')
    i++
    if (i >= this.images.length) {
      i = 0
    }
    this.images[i].classList.add('show')
  }
  document.querySelector(obj.btnPrev).onclick = function() {
    this.prev
  }
  document.querySelector(obj.btnNext).onclick = function() {
    this.next
  }
}
```

```css
.photos {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative
}

.photos img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto 0
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-1">
  <div class="photos">
    <img class="show" src="https://cs9.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2018/04/14/4/152368263318662102.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cameralabs.org/media/lab18/12/26-1/Pobediteli-fotokonkursa-Dikaya-priroda-Rossii-2018_25.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cs11.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2018/06/08/5/1528444187125297930.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://dlyakota.ru/uploads/posts/2017-12/dlyakota.ru_fotopodborki_kanadskaya-priroda-na-snimkah-stacy-william-head_6.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <button class="prev">Назад</button>
    <button class="next">Вперед</button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: чтобы можно было создавать несколько слайдеров (slider1, slider2)

Comment: а что вы от меня хотите услышать? я только начал изучать js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(obj.btnPrev).onclick = () => this.prev();
document.querySelector(obj.btnNext).onclick = () => this.next();
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо! А почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: Потому,  что `next && prev` функции, а функции надо запускать

Comment: спасибо за помощь:)